# Programmatically Configuring Jenkins Mailer Plugin in Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins, configure, mailer

As the title suggests, I am trying to configure the Mailer plugin in a Groovy script to set fields such as the username and password. Is there a way to do that?

I have tried referencing the Jenkins API documentation and managed to get the plugin as such:

```
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.getPlugin('mailer').getPlugin().configure(...)
```

However, I'm not sure if that "configure" method does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perhaps ... ?

from:  [https://github.com/Praqma/JenkinsAsCodeReference/blob/master/dockerizeit/master/globalconfig.groovy](http://%20*%20@origin%20%20https://github.com/Praqma/JenkinsAsCodeReference/blob/master/dockerizeit/master/globalconfig.groovy)

```
  def jlc = JenkinsLocationConfiguration.get()
  jlc.setAdminAddress(config.global.jenkinsAdminEmail)
  jlc.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, this has exactly what I was looking for.